# Get min/max-value of 3d-plot

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, limit, axis

I have a 3d-plot in MATLAB composed of many 3d-lines (by `line([...],[...],[...],...)`). If I rotate the plot with mouse and the rotate-tool (clickable icon in figure-window) MATLAB rescales the axis all the time. I know that it is possible to manually adjust the axis limits by using `axis([...])`, but I dont know the min/max-values of the 3d-lines, or surface objects.

You can test it for yourself by typing `surf(peaks)`. The axis are constantly changing between 0-50 and 0-60. I am using R2011a.

Do you have any suggestions how to get the 3d-min/max values of composed 3d-lines/3d-surface-meshes, to be able to set the axislimits manually?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `axis equal`? `axis vis3d`?

Comment: `axis equal` does not work for me (but for `surf(peaks)`), but `axis vis3d` does indeed work. Interesting. If you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've not discovered the command `axis` yet. From [the documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#inputarg_style):

> axis vis3d
>
> Freeze the aspect ratio properties. Sets the plot box aspect ratio mode and data aspect ratio mode properties to manual.

Example:

```
> surf(peaks);
> axis vis3d
```

...no more random axis scaling changes.

If you *really* need to extract the min/max of the data (rare cases), you can use something along the following lines:

```
plots = get(gca, 'children');
zdata = get(plots, 'zdata');
if isscalar(plots)
    zdata = {zdata}; end

maxZ = cellfun(@(x)max(x(:)), zdata);
minZ = cellfun(@(x)min(x(:)), zdata);
```